# Geometry Nodes - Transfer Geometry Faces Materials to Instances on points

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, instances

I would like to add faces materials to instances, so if the face of my geometry is yellow, the cylinder on it, will have the yellow material.

And I want to be able change the shader on geometry face on the fly.

How I can do this please ?

Thanks !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please ask one question per post on BSE. Here's one way to do it, by realizing instances:

[image]

[image]

In Blender 4 you can use a Repeat Zone to create an instance type per each material, and so reuse the geometry without realizing instances:

[image]